# fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key " " does not exist

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is my setup:

- I use AWS Batch that is running a custom Docker image
- The startup.sh file is an entrypoint script that is reading the nth line of a text file and copying it from s3 into the docker.
- For example, if the first line of the .txt file is 'Startup_00001/ Startup_000018 Startup_000019', the bash script reads this line, and uses a for loop to copy them over.
- This is part of my bash script:

> ```
> STARTUP_FILE_S3_URL=s3://cmtestbucke/Config/
> Startup_FileNames=$(sed -n ${LINE}p file.txt)
> for i in ${Startup_FileNames}
> do
>         Startup_FileURL=${STARTUP_FILE_S3_URL}$i
>         echo $Startup_FileURL
>         aws s3 cp ${Startup_FileURL} /home/CM_Projects/ &
> done
> ```

- Here is the log output from aws:

> s3://cmtestbucke/Config/Startup_000017 
> s3://cmtestbucke/Config/Startup_000018 
> s3://cmtestbucke/Config/Startup_000019 
> Completed 727 Bytes/727 Bytes (7.1 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining download: s3://cmtestbucke/Config/Startup_000018 to Data/Config/Startup_000018
> Completed 731 Bytes/731 Bytes (10.1 KiB/s) with 1 file(s) remaining download: s3://cmtestbucke/Config/Startup_000017 to Data/Config/Startup_000017
> fatal error: **An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key
> "Config/Startup_000019 " does not exist.**

- My s3 bucket certainly contains the object s3://cmtestbucke/Config/Startup_000019
- I noticed this happens regardless of filenames. The last iteration always gives this error.
- I tested this bash logic locally with the same aws commands. It copies all 3 files.

Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong here?

Comment: It looks like there might be a trailing whitespace in the name of the last item. Can you check whether this might be the root cause?

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha there are no whitespaces. However this made me think about the EOL and turns out it was windows(CR LF). I changed it to unix (LF) since the docker image i run is Ubuntu. Now it works. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with EOL of the text file. It was set to Windows(CR LF). The docker image is running Ubuntu which caused the error. I changed the EOL to Unix(LF). The problem was solved.